# Silex rewrite, one.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, silex

I am using this apache rewrite, when i am on my local machine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /skoleskak/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But after i uploaded it, to my host i get server error. They told me they dont support Options, but i can't get it working without that.

I am trying to route my Silex installation, so its /web/stats/ instead of web/index.php/stats.

I found this example for Codeigniter http://www.chrishjorth.com/blog/one-com-codeigniter-htaccess-rewrite-rules/

Anyone know how to make it work with Silex?

Comment: Try commenting out `Options -MultiViews` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem at some hosters. If your server has installed Apache >= 2.2.16 you can use the FallbackResource command:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

in your .htaccess instead of

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /skoleskak/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

See also [Apache’s fallbackresource: your new .htaccess command](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/) for more information.